How to find interesting/important papers
I am doing a PhD in mathematics, and it seems like the other PhD students/post-docs always have long lists of recent papers they want to read (although they all say they never get round to it).
When I'm working on a specific problem, I'll collect a list of interesting/important papers relevant to it - but making this list takes a decent amount of time and tends to be a result of me thinking about which part of the proofs are important for me to understand in-depth.
How do people identify recent interesting/important papers which are not directly relevant to a problem they already know a lot about? Do people just search on arXiv and look at the recent papers in that field? And if so, how do you know if a paper is considered 'correct' or not?

No single paper is ‘correct’ - you need an ecosystem of papers to start approximating ’correct’.

Why do you want to "make a list" before you start reading?

Nearly the same way you stumble into most interesting-but-unanticipated things in life: get out there, keep an open mind. Avoid the trap of focusing on being a comprehensive paper hunter.

I am subscribed to RSS feeds in most relevant journals and have a filter set to highlight papers based on about a hundred of keywords and author names that I am interested in following. That gives a few hits per day. In addition I read titles on arXiv every few days to see if there is anything interesting there. It takes 5-10 minutes while sipping morning coffee. Only for about 10% of those papers, I actually read the abstract and for only 1% the whole paper. If you want to catch up on some field you didn't follow before, reading review articles is most helpful. Keyword search in publication databases is useful to find answers to specific questions.

Talk to people in your field to get ideas for what might be useful to read.
Join professional organizations in your field so that you have access to their journals or at least the ToC of their journals. Go to some of their conferences so that you can see presentations, but also talk to people in the field for what they think should be read.
When you read a paper, follow up on those it cites.
Search arXiv for keywords.
Carry a notebook and when you get an idea for something (topics) worth following up, make a note so that you can search the literature later. And make notes when you talk to people.
If you have access to citation indexes, look there for things that others seem to think are important. Talk to an academic librarian about this.
Not rocket science.

I recommend registering for Google Alerts for your field/advisor on the technical site and https://www.connectedpapers.com/. Following people in your field on social media also helps.
Regarding correctness: Make yourself comfortable with the journals and conferences in your field to prioritize and discard predatory publishers.

All of the answers already given are valid and useful, but there are some new AI driven tools coming out that might further help you, like ResearchRabbit, that basically takes a few examples and generate lists of related papers for you.
